# Visual Studio / Xamarin Forms - Can't find device

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've just installed VS 2017 with Xamarin Forms and have created my first MVVM app which works fine through the android emulator. But now I'd like to deploy this app to my own device (Samsung S7 - Android version 7).

For some unknown reason my VS cannot find my device - it's plugged directly into one of the laptops USB ports, developer mode is switched on as well as the USB debugging setting. I've installed drivers as well.

[image]

Hopefully you can see that image which shows a list of vs emulators for android on VS. All of which are API23 (Android v 6) - could this have something to do with the fact that my v7 device is not showing? I have API26 installed now which is for v7 of Android - still not showing..

Any ideas??

Comment: Try to change USB Connection mode MTP<->PTP

Comment: @Ive That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

change USB Connection mode MTP<->PTP